# jqgrid - how to dynamic add/remove defined subgrid in run time

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid 1.5.2, and I have a grid as subgrid, both parent and subgrid are in cell edit mode with no sorting allow.

In loadComplete event of the parent grid, I successful removed some of the subgrids which depended on the data of the row as the following:

```
loadComplete: function() {
  var dataIds = $('#mygrid1').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
  for (var i = 0;i < dataIds.length; i++) {
    var data = $("#mygrid1").jqGrid('getRowData', dataIds[i]);
    if (data[i].hasChild='N') {
       var grid = $("#mygrid1");
       $("#"+dataIds[i]+" td.sgcollapsed",grid[0]).unbind('click').html('');
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is

the data[i].hasChild can be changed by the user on the parent grid, so I want the subgrid is able to be expanded again for the row.

I've tried

```
$("#"+rowid+" td.sgcollapsed",grid[0]).bind('click').html('+');
```

to bind 'click' event back the element; however, it doesn't work, even the '+' sign is attached back to the subgrid column but click event do not fire...

Can someone give me any idea, solution or alternative for my approach, please? Thank you.

**Updated** on 1/6/2012:
After an all day diggings, and 'tries and errors', I found a way close to success, and the codings as below:

First, before I removed the binding of each row, I tried to store up the 'data and events data' with .clone(true,true) in an array.

```
currChild[rowid] = $("#"+rowid+"td.sgcollapsed",grid[0]).clone(true,true);
$("#"+rowid+" td.sgcollapsed",grid[0]).unbind('click').html('');
```

Then, I replace the clone back to the element by

```
$("#"+rowid+" td.sgcollapsed",grid[0]).replaceWith(currChild[rowid]);
```

I was happy when I saw the subgrid attached back to the row at the first changed; then, I tried to remove it by unbind it again, and seems no problem.

However, at the third change on the same row and trying to bring the subgrid back to the row, the subgrid column of the row was lost and has a column shift to the left on that row!

I tested every single row and they behave the same that get the row lost a column and shifted to the left on the third change.

It's a late night now, gonna have a sleep first; looking forward to hear any suggestions and I can move further on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is great morning and wanna give myself a game time, because I finally manage it and make this success!

The last issue, losting a subgrid column at the third change of the same row, was all because I hadn't made a clone for the element before I unbinded it again (I did the dynamic change in afterSaveCell event.)

```
grid.collapseSubGridRow(rowid); //collapse subgrid before unbind 
currChild[rowid] = $("#"+rowid+"td.sgcollapsed",grid[0]).clone(true,true);
$("#"+rowid+" td.sgcollapsed",grid[0]).unbind('click').html('');
```

So, after I have a clone before the unbind, every thing goes right and expected. Nice!

Also, if anyone has any workaround and improvement, or see any potential problem and correction, I'll love to hear. Thank you.